# compute maximum number of black rectangles in a cutome given black and white board

Tags: algorithm

ATTENTION: this is not maximal rectangle problem. this is about number of rectangles.

look at this picture:
[image]

I am looking for an algorithm to compute total number of blue rectangles(not maximal rectangle). this algorithm must be O(n^2) and we have a constraint that the board is Square(n*n) or in this picture m=n.

thanks in advance

Comment: See http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/tad.takaoka/cats02.pdf

Comment: You'd better post at least your initial attempt, and point out its flaws and ask for enhancements, because without showing a minimum effort, you'll hardly get an answer.

Comment: Well, one way would be repeatedly find max rectangle until you can't find anymore rectangles. And squares are geometrically rectangles, so count each shaded cell as well

Comment: So is your question "how many distinct blue rectangles there are"? The picture you attached is from the maximal rectangle problem...